# Command Prompt - see who is on network

Tags: command-line-interface

Using Command Prompt... can you see all of the users who are logged on a network?

Comment: How about you tell us what the "network" is. Is it a Windows domain, or a Windows TS environment. Is it a single Unix multi-user system, or is it a group of machines using the same auth mechanism? If so, what's that mechanism?

Comment: How about... I got it answered. Haha :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find some of the following commands helpful:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntadmincommands.php#Cmd01